# Will .stopImmediatePropagation () in click event of menu item interfere with the analytical tools?

Tags: jquery, html, ajax, google-analytics

**Background**

I make navigation menu which load subpages into div using ajax. Everything works fine but, when I go using menu to subpage, then back to main page and go to the same subpage again, bubbling happens and the subpage is loaded two times instead once. After repeating this a few times the subpage is loaded as many times as I visited it. To prevent this I used `.stopImmediatePropagation()`. Now page is loaded only once.

**Problem**

But when I was reading about bubbling I found this: https://javascript.info/bubbling-and-capturing The fragment titled "Don’t stop bubbling without a need!" says that blocking propagation, can cause error of functioning some analytic tools because e.g. `document.addEventListener("click")` don't see click event on menu element any more. This make impossible to track user on our web page.

**Question**

How to solve this conflict?

**More specific information:**

Example of navigation element:

```
<li><a class="nav" data-content="home">Home</a></li>
```

Script in index file for loading subpages:

```
var info = {
content: "home",
} //information which subpage is currently loaded, default value determine which subpage will be loaded at the beginning


loadContent(info.content); //load default content

function updateNavigation(){
    $('.nav').click(function(e){
        e.stopImmediatePropagation();
        var content = $(this).data('content');
        if(info.content != content){
            loadContent(content);
        }
    });
}

function loadContent(content){
    $.ajax({
        url: 'loader.php',
        type: 'post',
        data: {content:content},
        success: function(response){
            $('.page_loader').html(response);
            info.content = content;
            changeMenu(content);
            }
    });
}
```

Script at the end of each subpages called for update navigation. (I have .nav elements also in subpages):

```
updateNavigation();
```

and

```
$('.user').sorry(englishIsNotMyNative);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you can't stop propagation, check if element is target for event:

```
function updateNavigation(){
  $('.nav').click(function(e){
    if (e.target === this) {
      var content = $(this).data('content');
      if(info.content != content){
        loadContent(content);
      }
    }
  })
}
```